# Program returns to its main point unexpectedly at Pic C in MPlab

Tags: c, pic, mplab

I'm programming a stepper motor with PIC16F84 in MPlab IDE. My program returns it's starting point after I call it's delay method. To be more spesific, some of code snippets here.

main method to drive program

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
TRISB = 0; // PORT B as output port
PORTB = 0x0F;

stepForward(25);
activateRelay();
waitForSeconds(3000);
deActivateRelay();
stepBackward(50);
//Since step forward method steps for 100, this will return to initial state
stepForward(25);

return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Step forward method

```
void stepForward(unsigned int stepCount){
while(0 < stepCount) {
    PORTB = 0b00000001;
    waitForSeconds(500);
    PORTB = 0b00000010;
    waitForSeconds(500);
    PORTB = 0b00000100;
    waitForSeconds(500);
    PORTB = 0b00001000;
    waitForSeconds(500);
    stepCount--;
    }
}
```

And the method for delaying system

```
void waitForSeconds(unsigned int miliSeconds){
    //DelayUs(miliSeconds);
    for(;miliSeconds > 0; miliSeconds--)
         for(unsigned short x = 333; x > 0 ; x--){
         }
}
```

After the second `waitFor` method called from `stepForward` method, program returns into `TRISB = 0;` part of the `main` method.

I'm new at pic programming, so my fault would be very easy one. I'm looking for help. 
Thanks.

Comment: By "After the second `waitFor` method called from `stepForward`", do you mean that the second `waitForSeconds` completes successfully (and thus you see all the outputs go high 500ms after the PORTB1 goes high)?

Comment: Also, in MPLAB, have you enabled interrupts? I believe `INTCON` can be set by the device programmer, which could enabled interrupts. Since there isn't an ISR, this could potentially cause a crash as you describe. As a sanity check, add `INTCON = 0;` at the top of your program.

Comment: Probably it's not completed successfully, because it's not going into 3rd assignment of PORTB.

Comment: I've added INTCON = 0, but it didn't helped at all.

Comment: Probably operation `PORTB = 0b00000100;` is leading the CPU to a error handler state.

Comment: I'm out of options then sadly. Your code checks out, although it feels like the second assignment to `PORTB` is accidentally causing an interrupt (`RB0` is also the `INT` pin, although it shouldn't do that...). The only thing that it could be now is if you've accidentally connected RB0, 1 or 2 to a reset line :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the program counter jumps back to 0 unexpectedly, the PIC is resetting. There are many causes of reset, depending on the PIC. A common one is watchdog timeout, and you don't seem to be kicking the watchdog, so have you disabled it in the config bits? Status register bit 4 will tell you if a watchdog timeout occurred.

Comment: I disabled watchdog via `__CONFIG,WDT_OFF;` config bits, but I still have same problem. Thanks for reply.