# XC8 compiler: program returning to beginning of main()

Tags: c, xc8

I'm new to programming PIC microcontrollers, and I've been having some difficulty with a piece of code. In the `main()` function, it sets some registers, then enters an infinite while loop. In this while loop, a second function is called, which creates a delay (without calling any other functions, including `main()` then returns. However, it seems that when the second function ends, the program goes back to the top of `main()`, rather than continuing in the while loop.

Edit 1: I've done some more tests, and I still get the problem without the function, so it's almost certain that the microcontroller is resetting every second or so, for some unknown reason. There's supposed to be a register that tells you the reason for the reset, so I'll have a look at that.

Edit 2: Here is a very basic version of the code, in which the RC0 LED flashes briefly every 2 seconds (it should stay off).

```
void main()
{
    TRISC = 0x00;
    PORTCbits.RC0 = 1;
    OSCCON = 0b00000010;
    TRISA = 0x00;
    PORTA = 0x00;
    while(1)
    {
        PORTCbits.RC0=0;
    }
}
```

Edit 3: It turns out it was the watchdog timer causing the resets, fixed now by putting a CLRWDT() in the loop.

Comment: Please provide the code in question in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: Don't describe the code, show the code.  Describing the code say "this is roughly what my program does".  Problem is, computers don't do "roughly" what you tell them.  They do **exactly** what you tell them.  So tell us **exactly** what you're telling the computer to do.  I.e. show the code.

Comment: This is a common symptom if your MCU is resetting due to some power failure.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23085280/program-returns-to-its-main-point-unexpectedly-at-pic-c-in-mplab ?

Comment: Show us some code and we could help. First guess: Watchdog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be quite a few things, checking the RCON or equivalent register should help discern the cause, also provide the part number and part voltage.  Some of the possibles are: 
- Watchdog timer tripping,
- Brown-out on protection tripping,
- Stack over/underflow,
- Your code is jumping off into space (bad pointer?),
- Your code is performing a software reset,
- Your dividing by 0,
- others...